# Power series and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to prove that this series $$ p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k $$ converges for $x=(\frac67)$ and then find the value of $p(\frac67)$.

For the first one I used the formula to find the radius of convergence $$\frac{1}{\limsup_{x\to 0} \sqrt[k]{|a_k|}}$$ that equals to $0$.

Now I have to find the value of $p(\frac67)$ but I don't know how to start.
My teacher explained to use the fact that if $|x|<1$ than it's differentiable. He said that following some differentiation rules I would be able to find something like $$p(x)=(\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k)'=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
but I really have no idea how it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the series:

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$$

Which we recognise as the geometric series, and which we know converges for $|x| < 1$. Differentiating, with respect to $x$ we get:

$$S^{\prime} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$$

So we can write your function as $p(x) = xS^{\prime}$. We have that the infinite gemometric series can be written (for $|x|<1$) as:

$$S = \frac{1}{1-x} \implies p(x) = xS^{\prime} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

You can now substitute in your value of $x$ to find your final answer.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it becomes more clear :)